# Verify a JWT Token issued by Entra AD App Registration in Asp .NET core

Tags: authentication, asp.net, entra-id

I right now have an Entra/Azure AD App registration that is being used by a small Angular SPA to authenticate it to .net core APIs.

when I decode the JWT the iss is

```
 "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/64..............a21/",
```

and in my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["https://login.microsoftonline.com/64..............a21"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["http://localhost:5036/"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey
        (Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["?????"])), //this is what i feel like I am missing
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});
```

I am getting 401's when running my angular app in local dev mode and the API locally too . I was following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-register-app) to make the app registration

So my question is - how can I get the signing key so that my app can validate JWT tokens from Azure.